# Не работает сенсорный экран в ноутбуке Asus после переустановки windows

Tags: windows, драйвер, asus

Не работает сенсорный экран в ноутбуке Asus после переустановки windows. Сенсорный экран перед переустановкой системы работал. Повторная установка виндовса не помогло. HID-touchscreen в диспетчере устройств нету.
модель ноутбука asus s 13 oled

Comment: Драйверы поставил?

Comment: @Qwertiy нету драйверов для дисплея на оф сайте

Comment: @ВікторГоробчук Вы уверены? Я, конечно, не на 100% уверен, что выбрал именно вашу модель в списке на сайте поддержки ASUS (s13 oled есть в нескольких сериях ноутбуков), но вот что я вижу в драйверах: "Этот пакет включает драйвер сенсорной панели ASUS, который обеспечивает взаимодействие между сенсорной панелью и операционной системой для обеспечения плавного и точного управления кончиками пальцев с поддержкой жестов."

Comment: @ViktorTomilov это для тачпад, а у меня тачскрин не работает